# Is there a better way to define this matrix according to its actual dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Define the rows of some matrix $\mathbf{R}\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ as $\mathbf{r}_{1}^{\top},\mathbf{r}_{2}^{\top},$ and $\mathbf{r}_{3}^{\top}$ and define $\mathbf{t}=\begin{bmatrix}t_{1}&t_{2}&t_{3}\end{bmatrix}$. Define some scalar parameters which don't matter for the purpose of this question. Finally define the perspective projection matirx :
$$
\mathcal{M}:=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha \mathbf{r}_{1}^{\top}-\alpha\cot(\theta)\mathbf{r}_{2}^{\top}+x_{0}\mathbf{r}_{3}^{\top}&\alpha t_{1}-\alpha\cot(\theta)t_{2}+x_{0}t_{3}\\
\displaystyle\frac{\beta}{\sin(\theta)}\mathbf{r}_{2}^{\top}+y_{0}\mathbf{r}_{3}^{\top}&\displaystyle\frac{\beta}{\sin(\theta)}t_{2}+y_{0}t_{3} \\
\mathbf{r}_{3}^{\top}&t_{3}\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now this matrix is a $3\times 4$ matrix, but the way the authors have defined the matrix as such is confusing. My question is can someone help me write this matrix as a $3\times 4$ matrix element by element? We can even define $\mathbf{r}_{1}^{\top}=\begin{bmatrix}r_{1,1}&r_{1,2}&r_{1,3}\end{bmatrix}$ and do this for all the row vectors of $\mathbf{R}$ but it seems to complicated to adjust the entire matrix. Therefore, I would hope for some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course "pull" these vectors apart into their components but I don't think this would constitute a "better" definition of the matrix. So you'd get
$$
M := \begin{pmatrix} \alpha r_{11}^T - \alpha \cot{\theta} r_{21}^T + x_0 r_{31}^T & \alpha r_{12}^T - \alpha \cot{\theta} r_{22}^T + x_0 r_{32}^T & \alpha r_{13}^T - \alpha \cot{\theta} r_{23}^T + x_0 r_{33}^T & \alpha t_1 - \alpha \cot{\theta} t_2 + x_0 t_3 \\
\frac{\beta}{\sin{\theta}}r_{21}^T + y_0 r_{31}^T & \frac{\beta}{\sin{\theta}}r_{22}^T + y_0 r_{32}^T & \frac{\beta}{\sin{\theta}}r_{23}^T + y_0 r_{33}^T & \frac{\beta}{\sin{\theta}}t_{2} + y_0 t_{3}^T \\
r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{31} & t_3 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which imo is a way worse form to write it.

A maybe nicer way that "seperates concerns" would be to factor it. Define
$$
A := \begin{pmatrix} R & t^T \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} & t_1 \\
r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} & t_2 \\
r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} & t_3 \end{pmatrix}, \quad T :=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & -\alpha \cot{\theta} & x_0 \\
0 & \frac{\beta}{\sin{\theta}} & y_0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then
$$
M = TA.
$$

Comment: Indeed your suggestion is perfect, thank you very much!